# How to prevent apps appearing on Metro when installing on Windows 8?

Tags: installation, nsis, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a NSIS installer that installs my non-Metro application on Windows 8.

After installing, all the executables installed by my installer will show up on the Metro-style Start screen. Is there any way of avoiding that? Even the uninstaller exe is shown in the list, which is terrible in my opinion.

What's the best way to avoid installed .exe's from showing up on the Metro-style Start screen?

Comment: I assume you mean the Start screen?

Comment: Yep, the Metro start screen. Sorry, completely new to Win8.

Comment: Are you creating shortcuts to these exe files?

Comment: Yes, for Windows 7 etc. I create shortcuts in the Start Menu.
So, would I need to prevent any shortcuts from being created on Win8? Makes sense...

Comment: It does not make sense to not create any shortcuts on Win8 IMHO, once RTM ships we might have some guidelines from MS but until then you should probably just follow the guidelines for Win7 (Don't create shortcuts for uninstaller, readme etc, only create shortcuts for the main program(s).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented way to exclude something from the Metro start screen AFAIK. The only thing I could think of was to set the [System.AppUserModel.PreventPinning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property on the shortcut but that does not seem to have any effect (Other than removing pin from the context menu in explorer).

Comment: Disappointing answer... ;) Thanks a lot for your research and all the effort you put in answering this question!

Answer (score 5):

Set the [`System.AppUserModel.StartPinOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553605(v=vs.85).aspx) property of your shortcut to `APPUSERMODEL_STARTPINOPTION_NOPINONINSTALL`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is quite the answer you were looking for, but Microsoft [suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511447.aspx) you don't include things like uninstallers in the start menu; you should only include a shortcut to start the program itself. If you did this then you wouldn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8 Start page is the equivalent of the Start menu in Windows 7 and below. They are both launchers, where the Start page has more data and personalization, live tiles, etc., but their role is identical.